# the narrator keep trying vs. the narrator keeps

Tags: grammaticality

Is 'keep' or 'keeps' the right word to use in the sentence below:

> The documentary we are watching irritates me because the narrator **keeps** trying to force his opinion down our throats.

The subject of the verb 'keeps' is 'narrator', and it is singular, so 'keeps' seems the right choice.

The sentence is from http://www.ccc.commnet.edu/sensen/part1/two/writing.html

Comment: Yes, it's *keeps*: why should it be *keep*? [I can think of one uncommon construction where *keep* might be correct, but this isn't it]

Comment: the word 'keep' was used in the sentence where I read, so I posted this to get clarification. Post your comment as an answer, and I will accept it. (Ref:
http://www.ccc.commnet.edu/sensen/part1/two/writing.html)

Comment: That use of "keep" is grammatically incorrect. It appears to be a typo. Sorry about that, but you can't always trust what you see with your own eyes. Sometimes what is you see is unbelievable, as in this case.

Comment: This is frivolous. The editor's correction (at the reference cited) of "kept" to "keep" is to convey that the present tense is to substituted for the past. It is not to be taken in toto.

Comment: @Kris If that were the case then the source would not say *irritates* when changing *irritated*.

Comment: why is this downvoted at all?

Comment: The citation should be in the question, not in a comment. Comments are temporary. Please edit your question to show all the necessary context.

Comment: @MετάEd - FYI, added the citation in the main content.

Comment: @Kris- I quite didn't get your comment. Wouldn't it be still "keeps" even if the editor is to convey that the present tense is to be substituted for the past?

Comment: it would be great if people tell why they are down voting -- the feedback will help me to improve my future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it’s ***keeps***, as you have reasoned in the question.

Your [source](http://www.ccc.commnet.edu/sensen/part1/two/writing.html) is not correct:

> In history class <s>yesterday</s> **today**, I <s>got</s> **'m getting** mad. The videotape we <s>were</s> **are** watching <s>irritated</s> **irritates** me because the narrator <s>kept</s> **keep** trying to force his opinion down our throats . . .

I'm tempted to believe this is a simple typographical error where a single letter has been mistakenly omitted. It may not be deliberate.

To use *keep* **might** be held to be correct if the sentence were in what is commonly called the “subjunctive mood”:

> If the narrator keep doing that, I shall get mad

...but that is so archaic and awkward that it is almost perverse. To use “If he were to keep doing that” is not much better, and even there *If he keeps* is to be preferred.

Comment: This is the second question in two days where someone was trying to argue that an *if* clause should or would or might take the present subjunctive / modally marked / bare infinitive form in contemporary English, not in the the English of 2 or 4 or 6 hundred years ago. I wonder where this is coming from?

Comment: @tchrist Am I arguing for that? I don't think so.

Comment: No, please please do not misunderstand me. Of course you are not.  It just reminded me of it, is all.

Answer (score 2):

*Keeps* is correct. The reference material from commnet.edu is incorrect.

Comment: re: commnet.edu see my comment above.